# Error 403 when trying to access my virtualhost with XAMPP on Mac OS

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, xampp, virtualhost

I'm trying to create a basic virtual host pointing to a project in /Documents/Github/GSB/public with XAMPP on Mac OS.
I changed both my `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` files in order to do so, but everytime I'm trying to access my local website i get an Error 403 Access Forbidden message.

I checked the error logs and this is the message I'm getting :

> 1)Operation not permitted: [client 127.0.0.1:49285] AH00529: /Users/liliancarion/Documents/GitHub/GSB/public/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Users/liliancarion/Documents/GitHub/GSB/public/' is executable, referer: http://gsb.local/

I already tried solutions from different questions on stackoverflow like using the command `chmod -R 644` on the `.htaccess` file or using the command `chmod -R 755` on the root folder, I also changed the `httpd.conf` user and group properties or added permissions to the project's root folder, or even add the `Require all granted` to the vhost but nothing is working still.

If I understand well the error comes from the .htaccess file but I don't quite understand the error since the file is readable and its root folder executable

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` files:

```
# localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# GSB
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gsb.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/liliancarion/Documents/GitHub/GSB/public"
    <Directory "/Users/liliancarion/Documents/GitHub/GSB/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My project is in Users/liliancarion/Documents/GitHub/GSB/public

This is the permissions I have on the different folders

`drwxr-xr-x+ 21 liliancarion  staff  672 15 nov 20:04 liliancarion`
`drwxr-xr-x@  6 liliancarion  staff  192 15 nov 18:27 Documents`
`drwxr-xr-x@  4 liliancarion  staff  128 15 nov 18:27 GitHub`
`drwxr-xr-x@ 18 liliancarion  staff  576 15 nov 18:27 GSB`
`drwxr-xr-x@  7 liliancarion  staff  224 15 nov 18:15 public`

Comment: There is no sense in just trying all sorts of things. You need to understand what the actual issue is. Otherwise you will only mess up your setup.

Comment: So find out what user and group account the http server process is actually executed. Then follow all folders from the file systems root to that file. All folders need to be readable and "executable" for that process. The file needs to be readable. That apparently is not the case. And such error messages are precise in such things.

Comment: the errors says it comes from the htaceess file, so I made it readable as i made the root folder executable, but the error is still here so I tried different things that worked for other people, but thanks, I'll try to make the all readable and executable

Comment: As written above _all_ folders from the file systems root folder to that ".htaccess" file need to be readable and executable by the http server process. Not just the root folder itself.

Comment: No, I checked and made readable and executable every of the root folders and I'm still getting that same error... I used the `chmod -R 755`on all those folders and checked in FINDER that they were also all readable

Comment: Please add a sketch of the file permissions of that part of the file system to the question. Along with an excerpt of the process table that shows what user and group account the http server process is operated under. _After_ having restarted the http server process.

Comment: Also please check whether you have enabled MAC on your System, the Mac replacement for SELinux.

Comment: I added the permissions, how can I check what user and group are used for the http server?

Comment: As said: check your process table. Have a start with `ps -aux` if this is new to you.

Comment: And about the file system information above (please re-format it ...): I doubt that the http server operates under the user account "liliancarion" or the group account "staff".

Comment: yeah sorry i recently moved to mac os so all this is new to me

Comment: We all learn all our life. That actually is fun ;-)

Comment: Yeah thats right ! Alright so once I used the command I get the list of all actual running processes right ? so which one should I look for exactly for the http one?
Is it those ones? `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd`

Comment: Cause those are all performed with `liliancarion` so my user.

Comment: You operate the http server under your personal account? Exotic ... But then again: you are using XAMPP, not a normal setup. So I assume you did not really install that, but just operate it. Sorry, as you can guess I am not a Mac user, I used real Unix or Linux systems all my life. So that is where I am out of ideas now, as it looks. Sorry.

Comment: No problem ! Thanks for your time and patience anyway

Comment: You may be running into macOS' privacy protection system, TCC ("Transparency Consent and Control"), which is separate from the regular file permissions, and regulates access to "private" parts of the filesystem -- including users' Documents folders (see [this Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)). I'd try putting the files somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah I moved all my project in the XAMPP folder and now everything works, I guess I'll keep it like this for now, but I still don't know how to make it work when the project is outside of the XAMPP folder...